# Computing eigenvalues from characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This is a question in [Representation theory, a first course](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Representation_Theory.html?id=6GUH8ARxhp8C), where the authors try to explain why character theory turns out to be so effective for the study of representations of finite groups.

In particular they want to show by knowing the character $\chi_{V}$ of a representation of $G$, we can actually compute all eigenvalues (and their multiplicity) of any element.

I tried something but did not go very far. Also it seems a little bit vague that how much information of the group is available.

Can someone give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: @JackSchmidt If we know $\chi_V$, then we know $\chi_V(g)$ for all $g\in G$. I guess that is all Dominik used.

Comment: @JackSchmidt But $\chi_V$ is the character function of a specific representation $V$. It is not the character table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** Given $g\in G$, let $\rho_g$ denote its representation. Suppose that the eigenvalues of $\rho_g$ are $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. Then:

$$\chi(g)=\lambda_1+...+\lambda_n$$

$$\chi(g^2)=Tr(\rho_{g}^2)=\lambda_1^2+...+\lambda_n^2$$

$$\chi(g^3)=Tr(\rho_{g}^3)=\lambda_1^3+...+\lambda_n^3$$

$$...$$

$$\chi(g^{n})=Tr(\rho_{g}^{n})=\lambda_1^{n}+...+\lambda_n^{n}$$

If you are given the characters of the powers of $g$ this yields a system of equations of $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. By [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), the values of the elementary symmetric polynomials $s_1=\sigma_1(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n),...,s_n=\sigma_n(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n)$ are uniquely determined, so $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is the set of zeros (with multiplicities) of the polynomial $$P(x)=x^n-s_1 x^{n-1}+...+(-1)^n s_n=(x-\lambda_1)...(x-\lambda_n)$$

Comment: I thought about this, but I am not sure this system determines the eigenvalues. Is there a short proof for this? Thanks!

Comment: @HuiYu: See the edit.