# Computing irreducible representations of larger groups with GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

I'm currently trying to use GAP's function IrreducibleRepresentations() to compute the complex irreducible representations of some group $G$. We're using this function to determine whether each representation has a fixed point by taking the determinant of the representation minus the identity.

The problem is, for the groups that we're interested in (specifically the central extensions of $A_7$ and higher alternating groups) the program takes too long. Are there optimizations that we can make to have it run faster? We've already tried letting it run overnight.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the "fixed point" test -- if the representation has a nonzero fixed point it cannot be irreducible. But maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: Do you really need the representation. Character table + powermap let you get the eigenvalues+ multiplicities of the images of elements, so I suspect you could do your test using only the character tables of the groups (which will be much easier to get).

Comment: @ahulpke We are trying to find fixed points of specific elements, not the whole group. I'll try the powermap thing, do you have any more information about it?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427529/computing-eigenvalues-from-characters  and the GAP function `EigenvaluesChar`